# Get all parents ids from first level child up the tree in json data object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JSON data object, in which at different depths there are children:

```
var obj = {
    13: {
        name: 'Test',
        id: 13,
        parentId: null,
        children: {
            2: {
                name: 'Child',
                id: 2,
                parentId: 13,
                children: {
                    34: {
                        name: 'One More',
                        id: 34,
                        parentId: 2
                    },
                    35: {
                        name: 'One More Child',
                        id: 35,
                        parentId: 2
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I want to create function, which will be parse this data object in another structure of the following type:

```
var sortedObj = {
  'One More Child': [35, 2, 13],
  'One More': [34, 2, 13],
  'Test': [13]
};
```

I think I should walk the tree recursively, but have no idea how to start.
What is the proper way to create function to solve that case?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getNames(obj) {
    var ret = { }

    for(var id in obj) {
        ret[obj[id]["name"]] = [ id ];

        if("children" in obj[id]) {
            var children = getNames(obj[id]["children"]);

            for(var name in children) {
                children[name].push(id);
            }

            Object.assign(ret, children);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: When I use your solution I faced with a problem, when name object the same, they rewriting ((